# Importing Gift Aid records

Tags: gift-aid-extension

I am moving our memberships over to CiviCRM and we have a few thousand active members. I have implemented the Gift Aid extension and I would like to import Gift Aid records for all the existing customers. Can someone recommend a process for this or help me with api calls. I am happy to write php code but I can't identify which api calls are necessary.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import Gift Aid records with **Import Contacts**, but as they are as they are multi record fields, you have to use the ... option which is hidden away. You need to click on the **?** help for Import Records, which, at the end, gives you a link to the **Import Multi-value Custom Data** screen. Obviously you have to get your data into a suitable csv file to import and will have to add the contact id to match to the contact record (but easy enough with an export of all contacts and a lookup - checking duplicate names) or use external id if you have used one for the import of contact data.

[image]

Comment: Mick. Thank you very much for the help. It took me ages to find the option even after you told me where to look. Hopefully your answer will help others in the future.

Comment: Yes - it took me ages to find it as well.